# SQLite - SELECT TOP syntax error

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm trying to use the statement `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tasks WHERE dueDate < ?1 ORDER BY dueDate DESC` but SQLite says `near "1": syntax error`. What's wrong?

Comment: may be near this one: `dueDate < **?**1`

Comment: @najmeddine: If I delete the 1, I still get a syntax error so I don't think it's that one. I think "TOP" just might not be part of the SQLite syntax.

Comment: yes sqlite does not have 'TOP n' but 'LIMIT n'. My mistake just write it: `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE dueDate < ?1 ORDER BY dueDate DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Use `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query instead of `TOP 1` (which isn't valid [sqlite syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html)).

You might also need to remove the `?` in `dueDate < ?1`, but I don't know sqlite well enough to be sure.

Comment: like as  SELECT  * FROM Product ORDER BY _ID DESC LIMIT 1 because the top 1 is not permitted in sqllite syntax.